# CPU resets execution of custom C kernel when accessing global variable

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, x86-64, bootloader

Hope you are doing well during confinemet.

As a brief introduction: I write this question not as Tretorn, but as a member of ASOC, an association of computer science students from Spain. We are trying to learn how kernels work by developing one all by ourselves. We have te all the code (related to question) published in https://github.com/TretornESP/ASOC2

As we are around 30 students, we have splitted the job into: Filesystem, Memory, User-space software (merely shell), Process management and Bootloader.

When we are one month into developing, we have run into some real trouble with this last part, so here i am asking you for some help about the subject.

The steps we follow since the moment BIOS sets us up on `0x7c00` are:

- Set CS by performing a far jump (Thanks Mr. Petch!)
- Save main disk
- Set 16 bits stack
- Load 8 sectors from disk (2nd stage)
- Load 32-Bits GDT
- Load IDT
- Enable protected mode (CR0)
- Perform a far jump to flush pipeline and set CS
- Set all segments to the same (Flat segmentation)
- Set new stack to  `0x90000`
- Detect LM presence via CPUID
- Disable old paging (We didn't set up paging in PM)
- Set up page tables
- Activate PAE
- Activate LM
- Enable paging
- Load GDT (Same as in 32 bits, maybe in compat mode?)
- Far jump for same reasons as above
- Update segments
- Reset stack
- Call C kmain via `extern kmain call kmain`

Our linker script is:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary");
ENTRY(boot);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : {
        *(.boot);
        *(.text);
    }

    .rodata : SUBALIGN(4) {
        *(.rodata);
    }

    .data : SUBALIGN(4) {
        *(.data);
    }

    .bss : SUBALIGN(4) {
        *(.bss)
    }

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.eh_frame);
        *(.comment);
        *(.note.gnu.build-id);
    }
}
```

we compile with:

```
nasm -f elf64 boot.asm -o boot.o 
gcc -ffreestanding -nostdlib -mno-red-zone -fno-exceptions -m64 kernel.c boot.o -o kernel.bin -T link.ld
```

and test with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -fda kernel.bin
```

Our kmain kinda writes to VGA if we set the function like this:

```
void kmain() {

    char * vga_ptr = (char*)0xb8000;
    *(vga_ptr++) = 0x0f;
    *(vga_ptr++) = 'H';

    while (1){}
}
```

But if instead i declare `vga_ptr` outside of `kmain` bounds, the cpu resets the execution.

The assumption im doing here is that the CPU is triple faulting given the fact that the IDT is incomplete (any help with this would be appreciated too). The question is more of what triggers the exception that causes the double fault, triple fault, reset sled in the first place. Im just guessing but, maybe it has to do with incorrect paging or building process (friend `link.ld` gave us a lot of trouble in the past).

Any light poured over this problem, or pointing out any mess detected in our code would be greatly appreciated. And im sorry if the question was too long or inexact. Remember that we are students indeed (;

Have a great day and stay safe!

P.S. The full code of the bootloader is linked above in the github, in the branch BootTest. I tried to keep the question as short as possible, but under request i can edit the text to include any code fragment you need.

[EDIT] Another fail, maybe not related is that, when i dissasemble the .bin file, it shows everything under `.data` section.

Comment: Try to make a [mcve], there are a lot of files in that repo (some ambiguous: `boot.asm` vs `boot2.asm` and not reflecting the code you posted), and a lot of spaghetti coding. Your CPU is clearly triple faulting, bochs is better than qemu at debugging this issues because it can output a very verbose log that includes what lead to the TF. If you blindly copied the code from OSDEV then it won't probably work. I'd double-check the PML4 setup, particularly what mapping are you using? And why are you reloading the same exact GDT as used in PM (i.e. with no L bit set and then executing 64-bit code)?

Comment: It is also probably better is you break down your goal: 1) enter PM from boot and check that everything is OK (32-bit code executes, segments are set). 2) enable PAE and check that each page is correctly accessible (access an expected address for page) 3) enable LM and check that 64-bit assembly code is run correctly (including accessing the pages of above). 4) compile the kernel, check that the linker script is working and the accessed addresses are good. Check the kernel is loaded at its right address and execute it.

Comment: Thank you so much @MargaretBloom. Give me some time to sort the mess up with the branch, (you are absolutely right about it) and follow your advice on 2nd comment, i'll edit the question. Have a nice day.